# Wallet create_key api gives an error?

Tags: cleos, keys

What input I have to give to get a key?

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal Service Error",
    "error": {
        "code": 0,
        "name": "exception",
        "what": "unspecified",
        "details": [
            {
                "message": "vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1)",
                "file": "http_plugin.cpp",
                "line_number": 653,
                "method": "handle_exception"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cleos create key --file someFileName.txt
```

creates a keypair and saves it to someFileName.txt

```
cleos create key --to-console
```

creates a keypair and prints it to console.